# Add script to page at certain location in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

Generally we use the `wp-equeue-script` to add scripts to the page inside the header or the body section, but how about if I want to insert a script file at a certain location (like at the middle of the page)?

Furthermore, is it possible to generate dynamic scripts?

For example `http://xx.com/xx.js?query=xxx` which will return different scripts based no the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question, you can always add a `<script>` tag inside your template files wherever you like, would that solve it? Or alternatively add a function `<?php add_my_script(); ?>` somewhere in your template files which you put in `functions.php` and does some more checks to determine if you want a script there on that location and add it.

However, do  you really need it at a certain location in your page? It should not make a difference where you put the script, because you can wrap your functionality inside a function, and only run it when you call the function.

To answer your second question, yes you can, it's been answered before. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943198/parse-a-javascript-file-through-php

So don't call a .js file, call a .php file that renders your script.
just make sure the to use a `header("Content-Type: application/javascript");` and whatever logic you want there

Comment: Why I need to insert the script at the middle of the page is that I need to render the some contain as soon as possible (do not want to render after page ready). And for the second question, I have though that, but which `php` file can be used? Use plugin or something else?

Comment: You could add a custom page template (https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/)  in your theme, add a page with that template.

Answer (score -1):

When you use wp_enqueue_script(), you are enqueueing your file in the header or the footer, depending on the fifth parameter passed in the function.

A clean way to bring variables into a js file depending on your page's query : wp_localize_script() to bring localization or special request available into a js file.

```
 // Register the script
 wp_register_script( 'some_handle', 'path/to/myscript.js' );

// Localize the script with new data
$translation_array = array(
   'some_string' => __( 'Some string to translate', 'plugin-domain' ),
   'a_value' => '10'
);
wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );

// Enqueued script with localized data.
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
```

in the js script, you'll be able to retrieve the variables

```
<script>
  // alerts 'Some string to translate'
  alert( object_name.some_string);
</script>
```

Read more on the codex [wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)

If you want to load different js file depending on the query, you have to add php statement into the function call with wp_enqueue_scripts action (beware of the ending S).